# c# asp.net mvc - how to pass parameter into Url.Action

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc

I've created a basic weather forecast app. What im struggling to do is get the citys value from the input field, into my script. This is on my View:

So if the user types the city 'London' for example, script code passes 'London' as a parameter. How can i achieve this? I understand I must construct the URL using JavaScript but unsure how to.

```
     ViewBag.Title = "WeatherOrNot";
}

<h2>WeatherJS</h2>


<p id="reply"></p>
<p id="temp"></p>
<p id="humidity"></p>
<form>
   City:<br>
    <input id="city" type="text" name="city"><br>

</form>
<button>Get Weather</button>



<script>

    $(document).ready(function () {

        $("button").click(function () {
            $.get("@Url.Action("GetWeather","Home",new {City = "Mumbai" })", function (response) {
                //response
                $("#reply").text(response.name);
                $("#temp").text(response.main.temp);
                $("#humidity").text(response.main.humidity);

                //$("#city").get("city");
                console.log(response);

            });

        });

    });
```

I'm fairly new to MVC so apologies if this is very simple!

Thanks

Comment: You cant mix Razor and JS like that.  Get the url, then add your input value as a query parameter in JS

Comment: How do you mean 'get the URL'. If i'm trying to call the URL.Action method how could i get that url?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this work around

var enteredCity = $('#city').val();

```
$.get("@Url.Action("GetWeather","Home")"+"?City="+enteredCity, function (response) {
```

Comment: Hi Rahul, what im trying to do is get the city, in this case Mumbai from the input box.

So if the user types London, then in my Url.Action id pass in the City something like $(#city).val()  but thats not working.

Comment: changed my answer take a look now

Comment: thanks, I see what you did there, so we need to get the value into a variable and then pass it. makes sense!

Answer (score 1):

@Url.Action is server-side, whereas javascript is client-side.

So you cannot change a server-side element (e.g. @Url.Action) with javascript, you'll have to use a form.

```
$.get("@Url.Action("GetWeather","Home")"+"?City=" + $("#city").val(), function (response)
```

Answer (score 1):

ajax calls usually have a data property.. you can use this to set your query string values.   $.get(url, data, function)

```
var city = $('#city').val();
$.get("@Url.Action("GetWeather","Home")", new {City = city}, function (response) {
```

another way that might make more sense would be to use the full ajax syntax.

```
var city = $('#city').val();
$.ajax({
    url: "@Url.Action("GetWeather","Home")",
    data: {City: city},
    type: "GET"
}).done(function(response){
    $("#reply").text(response.name);
    $("#temp").text(response.main.temp);
    $("#humidity").text(response.main.humidity);
    //$("#city").get("city");
    console.log(response);
});
```